# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following: case The symbol "case" was substituted for ";" to continue

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a problem in my package body

Here is code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY emp_data IS
    PROCEDURE open_emp_cur_var(cv_emp IN OUT rt_emp, p_your_choice IN NUMBER)
    IS 
        BEGIN 
            CASE
                when p_your_choice=1 then open cv_emp for SELECT * FROM employees;
                else OPEN cv_emp for SELECT * FROM employees WHERE salary > 8000;
            end;
    end;
end open_emp_cur_var;
END emp_data;
```

It returns me it was compiled with errors.

This is two errors it returns me.

```
8/16      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:     case The symbol "case" was substituted for ";" to continue. 
11/1      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first `END` needs to be `END CASE`; and you have an extra `END`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY emp_data IS
    PROCEDURE open_emp_cur_var(cv_emp IN OUT rt_emp, p_your_choice IN NUMBER)
    IS 
    BEGIN 
        CASE
            WHEN p_your_choice=1 THEN
                OPEN cv_emp for SELECT * FROM employees;
            ELSE
                OPEN cv_emp for SELECT * FROM employees WHERE salary > 8000;
        END CASE;
    END open_emp_cur_var;
END emp_data; 
/
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use `IF..END IF` if you are unfamiliar with `CASE`

Also, you are probably looking for a `REFCURSOR` `OUT` variable.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE  emp_data IS
 PROCEDURE open_emp_cur_var (
          cv_emp OUT SYS_REFCURSOR , p_your_choice IN NUMBER
     );
     END;
     /

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY emp_data IS
     PROCEDURE open_emp_cur_var (
          cv_emp  OUT SYS_REFCURSOR, p_your_choice IN NUMBER
     ) IS
     BEGIN
          IF p_your_choice = 1 THEN
               OPEN cv_emp FOR SELECT *
                               FROM employees;

          ELSE OPEN cv_emp FOR SELECT *
                              FROM employees
                              WHERE salary > 8000;
     END IF;
     END;

END emp_data;
/
```